Database Engine to support Column References
I need to design a database/data warehouse that supports analytical queries on multiple tables. To simplify the problem, let assume two tables:
Orders(
  id int,
  company_id,
  amount float   
)

Companies(
  id int,
  segment_ids int
)

The segment_ids is an array of possible (int) values picked up from multiple segments, such as: Segment:Sizes{Small = 1 , Medium =2, Big =3} and Segment:Industries{Retail=10, Technology = 11, Other = 12}.
The query is direct: Find total revenue (Order amounts) of all Small Retail Companies (i.e, segment_ids contains 1 and 10).
This could be done pretty straightforward with SQLs (possibly with the need of flattening the Companies table into CompanySegments) and JOINs. However, this requires unpredicted data flattening and JOINs could be really slow because the Orders table can grow into billions.
I have checked Clickhouse, Google BigQuery and Cassandra, and various database engines, and it seems that they only offer the ability to cache/copy Company as a nested column (denormalization), and the cache has to be manually updated on every changing event.
I want to ask if there is a better type of DB engine that supports column-reference (to another table), i.e, something like:
Orders(
  id int,
  company ref-to-Company, // Reference to the Company table
  amount float   
)

So that we can immediately make query like that:
SELECT * from Orders where company.segments contains 1


This is a standard time vs space tradeoff.  Relational databases are really good at modeling the relationship-types you are talking about, but normalization costs processing time when it comes to queries.   Denormalization solves this, at the cost of duplicating the data.   It sounds like you aren't duplicating a lot of data, and it is a single integer field, so I would really consider just having a process which updates your segments on a batch-basis so that you can keep your orders table flat, or handling it as part of your insertion process.
There is no need to consider a whole other technology for this, this is what relational DBs are good at (and have done for many decades), you just have to decide what level of denormalization and latency you are comfortable with.
